# How do you access a variable in a Typescript file into a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For instance, I want to get the **feature_on** value as a result of an if/else statement in a typescript file in another javascript file.

```
var feature_on = false;
if(SOME_SPECIAL_STATEMENT === true)
{
   feature_on = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question bit more?

Comment: `feature_on` is a global variable ? Are you in the browser ? Are you using modules ?

Comment: I want to get the **feature_on** value in the typescript file and if the value is true, I will execute a function in the javascript file :)

Comment: feature_on is a global variable in the typescript file and yes I am in the browser and no I am not using modules.

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, I want to get the feature_on value as a result of an if/else statement in a typescript file in another javascript file

Compile TypeScript to get a JS. Then use the JS file just like you would already know / or can search for

Comment: I would like to just get the variable in the typescript file, as I am aware that it compiles to javascript :)